# Mod Rewrite problems

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am having some problems with mod rewrite. The server is Ubuntu 12.04, Apache2, Php 5.4.

I want an url like this:

```
www.website.com/<modelName>/<imageNumber>
```

And

```
www.website.com/<modelName>
```

To actually show:

```
www.website.com/showimage.php?model=<modelName>&image=<imageNumber>
```

And

```
www.website.com/model.php?model=<modelName>
```

I have put this in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2  [R,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$            model.php?model=$1               [R,L,NC,QSA]
```

I have checked that mod_rewrite is loaded in apache.
But the page just doesn't redirect.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the result is a 404 'the resource / does not exist on this server' and 'the resource // does not exist on this server'.

The strange thing is that I was playing around with it yesterday and tried to make a rule that included **website.com/model/modelName** and that seem to be in effect now and impossible to get rid of. I have tried to restart Apache ten times, clear browser caches and even install another browser that I didn't have before but the die-hard redirect from yesterday keeps going even in the new browser (FireFox).

Are the new redirect rules that I have written correct?

How do I put them in action?

Should I set chmod 777 on .htaccess?

Thanks a lot...

EDIT: here is some more information.

I only have one (default) site and the files (including .htaccess) are just sitting in /var/www

The file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default looks like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

I haven't changed anything there except Directory / AllowOverride All

.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/etc/apache2/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2  [R,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$            model.php?model=$1               [R,L,NC,QSA]
```

And I have run service apache2 restart endless times.

This url works fine:

```
/showimage.php?model=Ai&image=12
```

This one doesn't:

```
/Ai/12
```

HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2  [R,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$            model.php?model=$1               [R,L,NC,QSA]
```

Rather than going "this should work", I'll leave it to you by just translating the rules:

- The first rule will match **[anything]/[digits]** with or without a trailing slash and re-map to showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2 using a redirect, will break the chain (i.e. the second rule won't be executed), is case-insensitive (not needed), and preserves query string arguments.
  The second does the same, but model.php.

It is important to note that the second rule does not match an empty string (i.e. fetching /). This might be part of your problem.

The rules themselves are correct. You can test these on the rewrite tool at: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ .

What I believe your problem is is pretty simple. Please answer the following questions in a comment and I'll advise from there:

- Are you trying to fetch / without an index? If so, neither of your rules is matching it and that is why you're getting a 404.
- If not, what exact URL are you trying to fetch? Do you have access to server logs? If so, can you turn on the rewrite log?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am not getting a 404 with an "empty" url i.e. www.website.com. I am getting the front-page, which is fine. But requesting e.g. www.website.com/name/123 gives a 404 whereas www.website.com/showimage.php?model=name&image=123 works fine.

Comment: Can you add before the rewrite rules the following line: `RewriteBase /`. Let me know if it does anything.

Comment: I tried turning on the rewrite log by adding this into .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/etc/apache2/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$   showimage.php?model=$1&image=$2  [R,L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$            model.php?model=$1               [R,L,NC,QSA]
...But the folder /etc/apache2/logs remains empty

Comment: The folder remains empty? Okay. either you're running suhosin or your htaccess override is completely off. Go to your virtualhost config and add the following index to your options on the directories: AllowOverride all. This will turn htaccess back on if it is that problem. If it isn't, it won't do anything. More info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I added the RewriteBase / in the file, but no change. Please note that /model/<modelName> still works, even in "incognito mode" in Chrome and on machines/browsers that have never loaded the website before

Comment: Wait. What? /model/ **modelName** / shouldn't work, as the first rewrite only takes numbers! You're in a subdirectory?

Comment: That's why I said it seems to be using an older rewrite rule from yesterday. I don't know how to reset it and get the current rewriterules into action

Comment: That's not possible, unless something is overriding it. Apache's config order is config -> htaccess, and it recurses through directories. Do you, by any chance, have a set of rewrite rules one or two levels above yours?

Comment: no, I only turned on the module yesterday and I have only been "playing" in .htaccess sitting in the /var/www root

Comment: mod_rewrite does not "cache" itself. If in doubt, restart apache (/etc/init.d/apache2 restart). The only few options left are old rules in either .htaccess or a server config (VirtualHost or main), or... some inconsistency.

Comment: Got your edit. Couple of questions - is the /etc/apache2/logs/ directory in existence and owned by the apache user? (www-data by default). If it isn't, chown www-data:www-data /etc/apache2/logs .

Comment: The folder exists and I have chmod'ed it to www-data, it now looks like this:
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 May  2 17:31 logs

Comment: Good. You should start seeing log files appear. If you don't, can you temporarily chmod it to 777 as well?

Comment: It turns out that the apache 'error.log' is located in /var/log/apache2, I deleted the file and restarted apache, it says:

[Thu May 02 18:43:48 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: That's the error log. I'm after the **mod_rewrite error log**.

Comment: Wait a moment. Apache 2.2.22? Can you try this in your config: `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8`? This should pop a **LOT** of info in the error log of apache from mod_rewrite.

Comment: I suppose you mean apache2.conf. I get this error on restart:
Syntax error on line 208 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
LogLevel takes one argument, Level of verbosity in error logging

Comment: I don't understand this. I just tried to simply delete .htaccess and restart apache, but the old /model/'modelName' still works

Comment: Forget the `logLevel` directives, I'm thinking Apache 2.4 here :-( haven't used 2.2 in a while. As for the old /model/modelName working... I'm stumped on this one unless you have a caching proxy upstream, but that's highly doubtful. I'm at a complete loss and won't be able to help you much further without seeing server logs and your detailed set-up, I'm afraid :-(

Comment: I think I'll reinstall Apache and PHP and start from scratch

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I guess it's going nowhere. I'll re-install it all.

Comment: I have sort of gotten it to work now, but I have a weird problem. the redirect now adds /var/www to the url, so that www.website.com/<modelName>/ redirects to www.website.com/var/www/model.php?model=<modelName>. Why on earth is it now appending that?

Comment: What is your new rewrite rule?